# Deep Compression on YOLOv2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I would like to implement Deep Compression or any other technique to reduce the number of FLOPS on YOLOv2 Model. Please suggest how to approach this task.

It would be great if you could provide me with some reference(not paper).

Thank You!